# Como comparo a linha anterior de uma tabela e se igual exiba uma mensagem em php

Tags: php, sql, tabela-html

Olá estou fazendo um relatório onde as notas fiscais da mesma empresa sejam calculadas

[tabela que estou fazendo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heafv.png)

[Como quero que fique](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aswKS.png)

Tentei fazer desse jeito mas nao deu certo

```
$select = "select * from tabela";
$conexao = oci_parse($conn, $select);

oci_execute($conexao,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

$anterior = null;
$iguais = true;

while($row = oci_fetch_array($conexao, OCI_ASSOC){

$numero = $row['ID_EMPRESA'];

if ($anterior === null) {
              $anterior = $numero;
            } else if ($anterior != $numero) {
              $iguais = false;
            }

}

if($iguais){
echo 'dados iguais';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom, você pode resolver esse problema "direto da fonte", ou seja, através do seu SQL.
Algo nesse sentido:

```
SELECT sum(t.valor_nota), t.id_empresa FROM tabela t GROUP BY t.id_empresa
```

Dessa forma, você irá somar todos os valores da mesma empresa.

Resolver esse problema direto no código é mais trabalhoso, porém possível através de índices de array com o mesmo id_empresa, por exemplo.

```
$valor[$row['ID_EMPRESA']]['valor'] += $row['VALOR'];
```